# Collection initialisation using iif() throws ArgumentNullException

Tags: vb.net, initialization, short-circuiting, argumentnullexception

Can anyone tell me why this gives an error at run-time:

```
Dim mightBeNothing As List(Of String) = Nothing
Dim a As List(Of String) = IIf(mightBeNothing Is Nothing, New List(Of String)(), New List(Of String)(mightBeNothing))
```

I am getting `ArgumentNullException` on the second line. If I replace the last part with:

```
Dim a As List(Of String) = IIf(mightBeNothing Is Nothing, New List(Of String)(), New List(Of String)())
```

It works - but the constructor `New List(Of String)(mightBeNothing)` will never be called if `mightBeNothing` is nothing, so what is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the IIf function does not use short-circuit evaluation.  So it will always evaluate everything, even if mightBeNothing is nothing.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)  on the subject.

Comment: Thanks, I changed iif() to if() and it works as expected. Not sure why you would want iif not to short circuit, I just assumed it did.

Comment: IIf is a tricky little beast - I don't do a lot of VB.NET now, but a few years ago I was and it threw me for a loop because I assumed it would work like the C# ternary operator (?:).

Comment: Iif doesn't short-circuit because it's a plain function, not an operator like If.

Answer (score 1):

First, collection initializers aren't supported prior to VB.NET 10.

Having said that, the first example is passing in a null (Nothing) value for the third argument. The [IIf Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) always evaluate all three arguments, regardless of the true/false state of the first argument.  I believe that is why you are receiving the `ArgumentNullException`.

In the second case, none of the arguments are `Nothing` so it works, but doesn't give you the desired results.

I would recommend using an If Else:

```
Dim mightBeNothing As List(Of String) = Nothing
Dim a As List(Of String)

If mightBeNothing Is Nothing Then
    a = New List(Of String)
Else
    a = New List(Of String)
    a.Add(mightBeNothing)
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the IF operator instead of IIF.  It will short-circuit.  See this article on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx)